# Exporting from database to xls (laravel 5)

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

```
public function export(){
    view('tester');

    $assignments = DB::table('assignments')
        ->join('projects', 'assignments.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('people', 'assignments.person_id', '=', 'people.id')
        ->join('tasks', 'assignments.id', '=', 'tasks.assignment_id')
        ->select('assignments.*', 'projects.name','people.firstname','people.lastname', 'tasks.description','tasks.hours_spent')
        ->get();

    Excel::create('projects', function($excel) use($assignments) {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($assignments) {
            $sheet->fromArray($assignments);
        });
    })->export('xls');


}
```

When I click the export to xls

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{action('ReportController@export')}}">

                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  
                        <h4>Task Report</h4>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px">
                            Export to XLS format
                        </button>
```

The error is 
ErrorException in DefaultValueBinder.php line 65:
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. Please help me how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this easy and simple:-

```
$assignments = json_decode( json_encode($assignments), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename   = "Report-".date('d-m-Y').'_'.time();
Excel::create($filename, function($excel)use($record)  
      {
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet)use($record)
    {
  $sheet->loadView('view', compact(array('record')));
    $sheet->setOrientation('portrait');
    });

})->export('xls');
exit();
```

also make a view and show record in `<table>` but this view no call any layout part

Comment: use this query `$assignments = DB::table('assignments') ->select('assignments.*', 'projects.name','people.firstname','people.lastname', 'tasks.description','tasks.hours_spent')
        ->join('projects', 'assignments.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->join('people', 'assignments.person_id', '=', 'people.id')
        ->join('tasks', 'assignments.id', '=', 'tasks.assignment_id')
        ->get();`

Comment: I tried using this query in my code but it is giving the same error

Comment: I tried incorporating your code above with your query it now gives me a different error which is this: 
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [view] not found.

Comment: It is now working I removed this 2 lines of code
  $sheet->loadView('view', compact(array('record')));
  $sheet->setOrientation('portrait');

it now exports to xls but the xls file contains nothing.

Comment: $sheet->loadView('view', compact(array('record'))); $sheet->setOrientation('portrait');                                                add both line but this view page make record view like `<table><tr><td>data1</td><td>data1</td> </tr></table>` this show data export as xls

Comment: I added the two again but it's still doesn't work
The error is this: 
InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
View [view] not found.

Comment: how do i make a view? I'm sorry i'm new to laravel

Answer (score 0):

If I use DB to get the data I get the error ....

ErrorException in DefaultValueBinder.php line 65:
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```
$ret = Excel::create('statsExtract', function($excel) {
    $data = DB::table('thrps')->get();
    $excel->sheet('stats', function($sheet) use($data) {
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
    })->download('xls');
```

If I extract using the Eloquent Model ..... It works ....

```
$ret = Excel::create('statsExtract', function($excel) {
    $data = Thrp::all();
    $excel->sheet('stats', function($sheet) use($data) {
        $sheet->fromArray($data);
    });
    })->download('xls');
```

However, if I try add ->leftJoin statements I get an error that leftJoin does not exist ....